# Saving painted version of model

Tags: texture-painting

For some reason, when I go to 'Texture paint' and paint my model, it doesn't keep those changes when I get back to the normal object stuff, and I didn't observe much, but sometimes it even doesn't save my painted texture so I have to start all over again, anyone please help?

Comment: Blender will not automatically save your texture in the file. You have to save it as an image first.

Comment: And how can I do it?

Comment: All these instructions are weird and confusing.

Comment: @KapKing What exactly is confusing? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the UV Mode thing, tried ways to find the textures to be able to right click them and find 'Save' and tons of other methods I can't remember :/ but now it seems to have saved :D

Comment: Now I noticed, it keeps the changes from texture painting, but doesn't export the texture :/